# Как расположить элемент снизу в блоке css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: Что я имею]

Код:

```
<div id="mainContent" class="row">
        <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center">
            <h3>Чат.</h3>
            <div class="bg-light rounded" id="chat-block">
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" id="message">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Я должен поле ввода спустить вниз блока в котором оно находится. Как это сделать?

Comment: 1) Сделать абсолютное позицирование. 2) Использование **display:flex; и margin: auto 0 0 0;** соответственно. 3)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, так:

```css
#mainContent {
  position: relative; /* Чтобы абсолютный элемент внутри позиционировался относительно этого */
  padding-bottom: 20px; /* по размеру инпута */
  height: 200px; background-color: #ddd;
}

#message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /* Прилипнет к нижней рамке родителя (если у последнего будет position) */
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent" class="row">
  <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center">
    <h3>Чат.</h3>
    <div class="bg-light rounded" id="chat-block">
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" id="message">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но было бы легче просто разделить блоки, чтобы инпут пошел сразу после серого блока. А не был вложен в него.